# Fetch AWS Access And Secret Key

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

Infra is like API Gateway with handler Lambda functions. We have created 3 IAM users for 3 clients, Client execute API Gateway by providing Access and secret key. I would like to fetch Access and Secret key to identify the user.
Below code(In lambda) help us to get the User details.

```java
AWSCredentialsProvider credProvider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials("accessKey","secretKey"))
AmazonIdentityManagementClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(credProvider).build()
```

How do get the access and secret key? Context object in handler function only provides cognito identity object, However I have been expecting IAM Identity object with access and secret key used during the api call.

Answer (score 0):

Implement `RequestHandler<APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent, APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent>` .
For each incoming request event, you will get the below-mentioned details in **APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent**

```
requestEvent.getRequestContext().getIdentity()
```

Contains

```
    private String cognitoIdentityPoolId;
    private String accountId;
    private String cognitoIdentityId;
    private String caller;
    private String apiKey;
    private String sourceIp;
    private String cognitoAuthenticationType;
    private String cognitoAuthenticationProvider;
    private String userArn;
    private String userAgent;
    private String user;
    private String accessKey;
```

**As you can see, you will get userID in userARN along with accessKey.**